# what functionname().anotherfunctionname() means in C++

Tags: c++, oop

for example in C++ we use:

```
int a = 12;
typeid(a).name();
```

to get type of a variable

my question is what exactly typeid is (im nearly sure its a function but Clion shows nothing)
and if its a function how it inherites or something the name() function

i tried to get what type id is but Clion showed nothing (when suggestion pops up in Clion for example when u type na it shows the suggestion and it shows and f infront of name so i know its a function but for typeid its empty)

edit:
is there a way to make something similar?
nearly all 3 answers were really good i appreciate all of them

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Comment: [typeid operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) returns a [std::type_info](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info)

Comment: It's not a function it's an operator (`sizeof` is similar).

Comment: In general (more in line with name of your question) you can have functions that returning objects (or object references). So the first typeid(a) will return an object and then its member function name() is called immediately.  In other words it is a short notation for : `auto& tmp = typeid(a); tmp.name();`

Comment: It's perfectly legal to write `a().b().c().d().e()` just as it's legal to write `a()+b()+c()+d()+e()` As long as the types are right you can construct expressions as complicated as you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid), typeid

> refers to a std::type_info object representing the type type. If type is a reference type, the result refers to a std::type_info object representing the cv-unqualified version (since C++11) of the referenced type.

So `typeid(x)` returns a `std::type_info` object that has methods you can query:

[image]
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info

Answer (score 3):

The construct does the following: the first function call has a return value of an object, which has the second function name as a member function.

E.g. in a more generic context:

```
#include <iostream>

struct AnObject {
  void anotherFunctionName() {
    std::cout << "anotherFunctionName() member of AnObject was called" << std::endl;
  }
};

AnObject aFunctionName() {
  std::cout << "aFunctionName() was called, returning AnObject" << std::endl;
  return AnObject();    
}

int main() {
  // Return an instance of AnObject, and call its member function:
  aFunctionName().anotherFunctionName();
}
```

This will output:

```
aFunctionName() was called, returning AnObject 
anotherFunctionName() member of AnObject was called
```

Answer (score 3):

`typeid` is a bit special since it's a [**keyword**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword), which is likely why you weren't able to find too much information regarding it on CLion. Similarly you won't be able to find much on other keywords like `int` or `if`.

Nonetheless, the result of using `typeid(some_variable)` would be an [`std::type_info`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info)(a perfectly fine class), which would allow you to continue calling member functions like `.name()`.